# foursquare Userless access curl php

Tags: php, foursquare

I'm call the foursquare api with the `userless access` approach in php using curl. 
The foursquare endpoint `venues search`  is supposed to support userless access.

```
$city = urlencode($city);
$location= urlencode($location);

$url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?query=' . $location . ' &near=' . $city . '&v=20130815&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx'; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
```

The response:

```
[code] => 400
   [errorType] => invalid_auth
   [errorDetail] => Missing access credentials. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html for details.
```

afaik, using the 'userless access' approach does not require oauth. I'm including the client id and secret. 
So why am I getting an 'invalid_auth' error ?

if I enter the output of $url in a browser, I get a correct response. If I hard-code the $url, then curl returns a correct response. So why would the dynamic $url generate auth error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: 
`' &near='` should be `'&near='` -argh